# Scan a list of urls for keywords

Tags: python

**Hello**, I have a list of *URLs* that I'd like to search for keywords Inside them! Is there any program or tool that can help me with this? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _program_? You can use `grep`, you could use regex and you could also use `ctrl + F`. Be more precise, provide the input and what you would like as output

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
    for url in url_list:
        for keyword in keywords:
            if url.find(keyword) != -1:
                print(url)
```